# Does mounting squashfs put the whole filesystem in RAM?

Tags: linux, mount, compression, ram, squashfs

Situation: I've got a larger (>10GB) read-only collection of small files with loads of duplicates that I need to have available on multiple machines, even on different file systems. We can assume Linux kernel > 5.3.0.

One solution would be to put these into a squashfs image file, use deduplication and zstd compression when creating it, and mount that. Now, this can only work out for me if mounting doesn't mean that all files need to fit in RAM.

Is mounting a compressed squashfs file system like that always a decompress-fully-to-RAM business?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mounting a squashfs file system doesn’t involve decompressing it into memory; decompression is done on the fly, as necessary. There is [a small internal cache](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/squashfs.html#squashfs-internal-cache) to avoid repeatedly decompressing the same data, but that’s all.

squashfs file systems can store up to 2<sup>64</sup> bytes of data, so it wouldn’t be practical to decompress them fully on mount.